# Compilation warning with gnuplot

Tags: c, compilation, gnuplot, compiler-warnings

I want to use gnuplot in my code in Linux, so I wrote this line:

```
FILE *gnuplotPipe = popen ("gnuplot -persistent", "w");
```

And the compiler gave me this warning:

```
warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

Can someone explain me what is this warning? and what should I do in order to do it correctly?

Comment: are you sure the warning is from this very line?

Comment: Did you include `#include <stdio.h>` at the top?

Comment: @SouravGhosh it can very well be.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant yes, right, while not having the forward declaration [header file].

Comment: I included the stdio.h

Comment: `popen` may not be defined if you're using an old way to compile your code. Can you show 1/ a minimal example fully compilable example that shows this problem, and 2/ your compilation command?

Comment: @Evert I think you're right. I compiled the source code with -ansi flag, and when I remove this flag it's O.K

Comment: I don't have the defaults in my head, but I guess C ANSI is old enough to predate `popen` (its manual page lists POSIX.1-2001). I tend to use `-std=c99` these days, but that will also limit the functions available (which then again, can be bypassed using macros, e.g. with the `-D` option).

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

at the top of your file.

The header file contains the definitions for functions, including that of `popen()`. It tells the compiler `popen()` returns a `FILE *`.

If you don't include the header file, the compiler will assume a default return value, which is an `int`. Hence the warning can be explained: the compiler thinks `popen()` returns an `int`, and then wants to assign it to a `FILE *`.

Comment: I included the stdio.h